# Javascript or HTML DOM function required to hold values of textarea for my chrome extension

Tags: javascript

My code is :

```js
var menuItems = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
for (var menuItemIndex = 0 ; menuItems.length ; menuItemIndex ++){
    var currentMenuItem = menuItems[menuItemIndex];
    currentMenuItem.value = "Items changed:\n\nDescription of change:\n\nDescription of test:\n";
}
```

But when I am clicking to the event "Attach" the values in `currentMenuItem.value` are coming but the value which I am filling manually in front of **Items changed, Description of Change, Description of Test** i.e ABC, XYZ, FGH are not coming.

[image: screenshot of output in gui]

Comment: You made yourself an infinite loop.

Comment: I want these values to be populated all the time when I will be into the webpage but I need the manual values as well but not all the time when clicking "attach" the manual values should be there but after submitting it should be vanished . Is there any way out ?

Comment: you should attach an eventlistener (change event) on your textareas, and the for each respectively have some kind of object/array so that you store there input values inside of them

Comment: @EugenSunic if you can give example :)

Comment: @Nischay check the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use regex once you obtain the value of the entire textArea.

Extract the values for all three rows, after inserting the text click on the attach button and you it should console.log the output string.

Insert the following text in the textarea for testing:

> Items changed: ABC
>
> Description of change: EFG
>
> Description of test: HIJ

```js
function getTxtAreaValues() {
  const txtAreaContent = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].value

  const regexExpresion1 = /Items changed:(.*)/g;
  const regexExpresion2 = /Description of change:(.*)/g;
  const regexExpresion3 = /Description of test:(.*)/g;

  const match1 = regexExpresion1.exec(txtAreaContent)[1];
  const match2 = regexExpresion2.exec(txtAreaContent)[1];
  const match3 = regexExpresion3.exec(txtAreaContent)[1];


  const outputString =
    `Items changed:${match1}\n
     Description of change:${match2}\n 
     Description of test:${match3}\n 
`;
  return outputString;
}


document.getElementById('attach').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const values = getTxtAreaValues();
  console.log(values);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You made an infinite loop with your current code!

Your `for` instruction should look like this :

```
for (var menuItemIndex = 0 ; menuItemIndex < menuItems.length ; menuItemIndex ++){
```

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

Answer (score 0):

I think your `for` loop is meant to look like this:

```
for (var menuItemIndex = 0 ; menuItemIndex < menuItems.length ; menuItemIndex ++){
```

With your current implementation, it will be an infinite loop.

Comment: I want these values to be populated all the time when I will be into the webpage but I need the manual values as well but not all the time when clicking "attach" the manual values should be there but after submitting it should be vanished . Is there any way out ?